# How to call spring boot rest services from electron js application

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, electron

I am very much new to electron JS I am trying to create a desktop application using electron js and spring boot. I just installed node JS, then with the basic commands, I have created the "Hello world" electron js application. I have also created a spring boot application but I am not getting How to call spring boot rest services.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
});
```

Comment: https://codehandbook.org/how-to-make-rest-api-calls-in-express-web-app/   covers adding another "route" to your sample above .. Within the new route , do async call , await the http response and THen consume the rest response on go on with flow .

Comment: can we use vue.js??